# Display drop down in freemarker from properties file

Tags: freemarker, properties-file

```
 *I have to display US states in dropdown in .ftl file.I have stored data as key value pair in properties file as given below. I have to read data from properties file and display in ftl file.
    AL=Alabama
    AK=Alaska
    AZ=Arizona
    AR=Arkansas
    CA=California
    CO=Colorado
    CT=Connecticut
    DE=Delaware
    DC=District of Columbia
```

//I have to display drop-down as given below.I am beginner to free-marker.Could anyone please help me to do that.

```
    <select>
      <option value=AL>Alabama</option>
      <option value=AK>Alaska</option>
      .
      .
    </select>
```

Comment: freemarker is a template-engine, are you using some other framework for your application? (if you are using Struts there are easy-to-use tag libraries for example)

Comment: I am using Spring

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a framework that provide a `select` tag you can use it like this:

```
<form:select items="${countryMap}" /> <!-- SpringMVC -->
<@s.select list="countryMap" />  <!--Struts2 -->
```

where `countryMap` in both cases is a key-value `Map` exposed (available) to the template where you have read and stored your properties.

In pure freemarker would be like this:

```
<select>
    <#list countryMap as key, value>
        <option value="${key}">${value}</option>
    </#list>
</select>
```

Also [this page](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-dropdown-box-example/) can help you.